# How to delete photos

Tags: photos.app

I want to delete photos in the new photos app but can't find any delete or trash icon. Where is it?

I tried highlighting the photos I want to delete, but I can't find the trash icon. I understand there is a selection to permanently delete but can't find it either?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out!!! You highlight the desired photos you wish to delete, then press the delete button. They are then moved to a recently deleted album.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you mean deleting from the database not removing from an album!
For me pressing "Cmd+Backspace" does the job in any occaion.